# Is there any tool/software to generate the Unit test file automatically for ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

Do you know is there any tool/software that generates the Unit test cases automatically for ReactJs App.?

- I am Trying to implement the automated tool that generates unit test cases and expects the possible test scenarios - just wanted to check is there any tool exist?

Answer (score 1):

You should write tests by yourself, there is no tool that can understand code and write tests for you.

Comment: Oh Thanks!, I am implementing one tool in node js that expects the possible testing cases - So wanted to check is there any tool exist.